# преобразование base64 в файл

Tags: php, base64

С клиента на сервер приходит JSON формы, в одном из полей которой хранится картинка в виде base64. Как эту картинку средствами PHP 5 сохранить на сервер в файл по нужному пути?

Сделал вот так:

```
$base64_decode  = base64_decode ($response["image_opt"]);             
$dirSave = DOCROOT.'uploads/'. uniqid(). '.jpg';
file_put_contents($dirSave, $base64_decode);
```

Файл на диск сохраняется, но не открывается через просмоторщик Windows.

Comment: А какая у вас проблема? Вы не можете найти функции base64_decode() и file_put_contents()?

Comment: дописал вопрос, не получается

Comment: скорее всего вам присылаются вместе с типом base64, т.е. вам нужно разделить строку по символу `,` и брать все что после запятой и сохранять

Comment: покажите вывод $base64_decode

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function base64ToFile($data, $path) {
    $source = fopen($data, 'r');
    $destination = fopen($path, 'w');

    stream_copy_to_stream($source, $destination);
    fclose($source);
    fclose($destination);
}
```